# How to retrieve previous audio volume while the current volume is muted?

Tags: java, android

By using the following code we can mute the music playback:
`audioManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,AudioManager.ADJUST_MUTE,0);`

And after that when we try to retrieve the volume:
`audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);`
it returns **0**

Is there a way to find what the volume would be after we unmute? It should be the previous volume right before we set it to mute. But how to retrieve that value?

I know that we could just save the value right before muting it, but what if the app restarts? We then have to rely on persistent storage. Even then we cannot guarantee that the value hasn't changed.

So, I would like to know if there is any way to extract the value without having to save it.

Answer (score 1):

[AudioManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager) doesn't provide that kind of functionality.

I think you need to save it in a local storage to achieve what you want. Shared preferences is ideal in this case.